# MS SQL 2008: View "variable" instead of JOIN

Tags: sql-server-2008

Basically we have a view that needs optimizing.
The view now looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM IM_Data.history.v_SystemInfo si
INNER JOIN IM_Data..systemOutDates od ON
    si.TopId = od.TopId
    AND si.OutDate = od.OutDate
WHERE 
    TopId = 196
```

If I could let the view be like this (which I obviously can't):

```
SELECT @OutDate = OutDate 
FROM IM_Data..systemOutDates
WHERE TopId = 196

SELECT *
FROM IM_Data.history.v_SystemInfo si
WHERE 
    TopId = 196 AND
    OutDate = @OutDate
```

It would be 10 times faster. So what I'm looking for is someone that knows SQL good enough to help me out with this. I basically need the query to query TopDate once and then use the same on all rows, not join on every row (cause that's the time waste).

And I can't remove TopDate and let the user querying the view handle it because it's too much legacy code using the view. So the only option is to let let the user query it as it is right now but somehow still solve the performance loss of the join.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing I would change is SELECT *, if that's in your view, better to put specific columns than *. And if your view is SELECTing from other views, might be better to hoist the embedded view into the top level.

Comment: The reason I have SELECT * is cause the view is selecting from a history view that has the columns specified. It justs selects on a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but you could either use a subquery or join the condition table temporarily to just obtain one result. Without examples of your structure it is almost impossible to tell whether there is a better option.
I guess something like this might come close to what you want - have a look at the query costs to see if it helps.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    IM_Data.history.v_SystemInfo AS si INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 OutDate FROM IM_Data..systemOutDates WHERE sourceId = si.TopId) AS    tblOutDate
WHERE 
    si.TopId = 196 AND si.OutDate = tblOutDate.OutDate
```

Comment: Using a subquery results in the subquery being called on every row, so that's the same as the original join =/

Comment: This doesn't compile, because you haven't specified an ON clause after the join. Also, this kind of subquery (a derived table) can't reference the outer query's tables.